# Preventing servo motor and drive ground loops in shielding

Tags: grounding, emc, encoder, ground-loop

[image]
I have an XYZ CNC machine that has an electrical panel with industrial servo drives.
I recently had an EMI problem on the encoder cable for one of the motors, and tried to diagnose the problem.
The servo drives are Yaskawa SGD7S series.

I disconnected the motor power cable shield from the terminal on the servo drive, but the multimeter said that it was still connected to earth.
It was the same on the shield of the encoder cable.
This seems to be, because the motor power cable's shield is connected to the motor chassis, which is connected to the machine chassis through mounting bolts, which is connected to the panel, as the panel is mounted to the machine.

According to online sources, shields have to be connected to earth at one point only, but here there is a ground loop:
Panel-servo drive-power cable shield-motor chassis-machine chassis-panel

I'm sure this is a common problem, but I'm wondering about the best way to solve it. Should I isolate the motor from the machine chassis, or isolate the panel from the machine chassis? Or something else...

Edit: If I disconnect the machine chassis from the panel, I will still have a ground loop through the shields of the 3 motor cables. It seems that the motor has to be isolated from the machine chassis?

Comment: A schematic or wiring diagram would be really helpful for this kind of question, including where your problems/measurements are.

Comment: @LordTeddy done!

Comment: How have you proven you actually have a ground loop problem? Current has to flow for there to be a problem. Have you measured it?  The shields must be connected at both ends otherwise you have an antenna.

Comment: @Kartman Thanks for your comment, I have not proven it, but thought it's a problem either way for the shield to be grounded at both ends. I have searched up shields that are grounded at both ends, and have found some people saying it is a myth that shielding must always be grounded at one end. Single end grounding seems to be more important if the ground is used as a return path. The issue must be elsewhere.